# Galen/Selenium : Paypal Login process

Tags: android, selenium, paypal, saucelabs, galen

For desktop, On click on paypal btn, new window open on which user fill their crediantials and then it goes back to original page.

To handle this, i wrote following code

```
    winHandle = driver.getWindowHandles();
    console.log("no. of window "+winHandle.toArray().length); //1 for mobile
    handle = winHandle.toArray()[winHandle.size() - 1];
    console.log(handle);
    previousHandle = winHandle.toArray()[0];
    //On paypal login, a new window will open. Below code will handle the window switching. But this is not happening with mobile
    driver.switchTo().window(handle);
    console.log("switched to paypal window");
    paypalLogin = new PayPalLoginPage(driver);
    paypalLogin.proceedWithSandBoxPurchase();
    //switch to origin window
    driver.switchTo().window(previousHandle);
```

But problem with android and iphone is, on click of paypal btn no other window is open but paypal page appears.

When i try to find any element of this paypal page i get element not found exception.

Has someone faced this issue paypal login process in selenium or galen framework for mobile testing in saucelabs ? And how it solved?

Comment: what's your concrete setup? you have an android app with a mobile via which should open PayPal?  So you're using Appium?

Comment: Yes i am using appium. And run test on saucelabs.

Comment: so you have an android app and open in this app a PayPal web view?